# why the sentence if form.is_valid(): never pass. i have tried many thing, changing the python version for example and always is the same

Tags: python, django

**When I run the code, it never pass the sentence **if form.is_valid():****
**I have changed the version of python, but it is still the same**

### views.py

```
def login_page(request):
    form = Loginform(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    print("User logged in")

    if form.is_valid():
        # print("form is validated")
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        # print("form cleaned data")
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
```

### forms.py

```
from django import forms
class Loginform(forms.Form):
    username = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

### view.html

```
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col'>
          <p>{{ content }}</p>
          <div class='col-sm-6 col-12'>
          <form method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                <buttom type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Submit</buttom>
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>

   # The form looks well, same the submit. I do not see the error
```

please help me to undertand what happens with this sentence of form_is_valid

Comment: `print(form.errors)` after the `if` body part.

Comment: The expression `request.POST or None` looks odd for me. Are you sure, that it is corect?

Comment: @jottbe: I think there are some videolecture that promote this, since often questions contain this. Often this works, but for forms where it is not required to have any input, it can result in an unbounded form, even if it was valid. The `or None` will evaluate the truthiness of `request.POST`, which is `True` if it contains at least one element. If it does not `None` is used. This is a "trick" not to brach between a POST and GET request, but it is thus not entirely correct.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: thank you for the explanation. I was not aware that or just returns the second expression, if the first is wrong. I thought it would always return a truth value. But it still looks a bit hackish to me :-)

Comment: @jottbe: it is. `x or y` will evaluate the *truthiness* of `x`. For example `None` has truthiness `False`, for numbers normally *zero* has truthiness `False` and for collections (so *including* a `QueryDict`) and strings, it is `False` in case it contains no elements, most other objects have truthness `True`. In case it is `True`, it will return the first element, in case it is `False` it will evaluate `y`. A special case is where `x` and `y` are `True`/`False`, since the truthiness of `True` is `True` and of `False` is `False` that thus works as a boolean operator.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I know that part, thanks. I just didn't know that or doesn't evaluate the truthiness of the second argument but just returns it as the result.